# Retrive the rows for a same date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want all the rows between two dates. I tried **between** but it doesn't show value for same date i.e., 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-01. In this case the result is null. But if i give dates like 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-02. It shows 10 rows for the 2013-01-01 whole day. Any ideas guys how to solve this in MySQL. My query is like this

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(access_date) as date,
       DATE_FORMAT( access_date,'%d/%m/%Y') as month_date ,
       COUNT( log_id ) as total_count
FROM user_activity_log 
WHERE dam_id =
         (SELECT dam_id FROM dam_content_details
                 WHERE content_type= 'userLogin') AND
                 access_date >= '2013-01-03' AND
                 access_date <= '2013-01-03'
                GROUP BY MONTH( access_date ) 
                ORDER BY access_date ASC
```

Comment: Are you using a temporal data type (DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP) for your access_date column?

Comment: I think you should look at joining table, using the join command

Comment: How to do that by join can you explain ?

Comment: @GordonM No i am not using anything.

Comment: I want the data between two same dates.

Comment: @RIADev you must be using something, there's no way the access_date column doesn't have a type.

Comment: @GordonM thanks for your effort buddy i got the solution please refer the cristian answer. We need to use CAST. Thank you guys for your time & effort.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(date_column) BETWEEN '2019-07-17' and '2019-07-17'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is like your test:

```
mysql> select  '2013-12-30 12:11:23' BETWEEN '2013-12-30' AND '2013-12-30' as test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```

This is the correct way to works with datetime values:

```
mysql> select  '2013-12-30 12:11:23' BETWEEN '2013-12-30 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-30 23:59:59' as test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

This is the workaround in order to work between date and datetime values:

```
mysql> select  CAST('2013-12-30 12:11:23' AS DATE) BETWEEN '2013-12-30' AND '2013-12-30' as test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

From [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html):

> MySQL converts a time value to a date or date-and-time value by
>   parsing the string value of the time as a date or date-and-time. This
>   is unlikely to be useful. For example, '23:12:31' interpreted as a
>   date becomes '2032-12-31'. Time values not valid as dates become
>   '0000-00-00' or NULL.
>
> Explicit conversion can be used to override implicit conversion. For
>   example, in comparison of DATE and DATETIME values, the DATE value is
>   coerced to the DATETIME type by adding a time part of '00:00:00'. To
>   perform the comparison by ignoring the time part of the DATETIME value
>   instead, use the CAST() function in the following way:
>
> date_col = CAST(datetime_col AS DATE)

Probably a bug in my opinion...

Comment: Hmm its quite interesting one...thanks buddy this "cast" is working fine...

Comment: It is not a bug, it actually works as intended. You even have the key sentence in the excerpt: "comparison of DATE and DATETIME values, the DATE value is coerced to the DATETIME type by adding a time part of '00:00:00".  So if the stored data is a datetime, and the range is date, then the range dates are converted to a datetime with '00:00:00' as the time part. If the stored data has a time part greater than '00:00:00', it just simply falls out of the upper limit of the date range.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-02-28' AND '2012-03-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `between` as in example:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table_name WHERE date_column BETWEEN '2009-05-28' AND '2012-12-14'
```

I you case it is :

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(access_date) as date,DATE_FORMAT( access_date,  '%d/%m/%Y'
) as month_date ,COUNT( log_id ) as total_count FROM user_activity_log WHERE dam_id =
(SELECT dam_id FROM dam_content_details WHERE content_type= 'userLogin') AND access_date BETWEEN '2013-01-03' AND '2013-01-03' GROUP BY MONTH( access_date ) ORDER BY 
access_date ASC
```

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

> - `expr` BETWEEN `min` AND `max`
>
> If `expr` is greater than or equal to `min` and `expr` is less than or equal to `max`, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. **This is equivalent to the expression (`min` <= `expr` AND `expr` <= `max`) if all the arguments are of the same type.** Otherwise type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 11.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

So it really is just syntax sugar.

Comment: Hey.. i already tried "between" my problem is the result is returning null for one day.

Comment: what do you mean 'for one day'?

Comment: i have two date fields. I will pass same date in both. Then how to calculate the data between two same dates like 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-01 . Got it ?

Answer (score -2):

Try changing like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-01 23:59:59'
```